# Nachos chip library in listview

Tags: java, android

I'm using nachos chip library within a listview to display tags. The problem is when touching chips/chips area it consumes the touch so onItemClick is never initiated.

Nachos chips are basically an EditText and I have set the xml as so:

```
android:editable="false"

android:focusable="false"

android:longClickable="false"

android:Clickable="false"
```

I can use the listview like normal when touching outside of the nachos chip but if it's on it then the touch event is consumed.

Does anyone have any kind of work around or idea for how to solve this?